# number in the color wheel is overlapping my popup window

Tags: css, html, user-interface, popup

[image]

once I pressed a button for the popup to appear, the popup window would overlap the whole GUI except the number in the colour wheel as shown in the picture below . any methods the I could use to prevent the number from overlapping the popup window?

the css:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.popup h2{color:#07839f; line-height:1.8em}
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%; color:#666;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
}
.overlay:target+.popup {
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.close {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: -15px;
    width: 30px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    content: "X";
    font-size: 24px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.popup p, .popup div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.popup label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 180px;
    color:black;
}
.popup input[type="text"], .popup input[type="number"] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px; background:#d8f6fd;

    border: 1px solid #66c8de;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#sync{
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #34b8d9;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: And how are we suppose to help you without any piece of code from your side?

Comment: Please put some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the css property **z-index** to the popup window and the zero number. You'll need to add `position: relative;` to both of the class(es)/id(s) though for z-index to work.